# Cannot debug javascript on webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying to get debugging to work on ff/chrome. I've checked all the post that come up when you google.

What I've done:
- setup a ff profile
- setup a in place deployment and double checked the remote urls..
- all plugins are enabled (including Javascript debugger)

As it seems the webstorm debugging extension was not installed in firefox (or chrome). I cannot find anything on how to get it installed. (I've allready tried re-installing Webstorm)

When I debug a file, firefox opens, but displays no page and the url-bar is empty..

I'm using Webstorm 4.0 and Firefox 11

Comment: JavaScript debugging in Chrome should work without any extensions. In order to debug in Firefox WebStorm uses an extension which should be installed to Firefox when you start the debugger for the first time. By the way, which OS do you use?

Comment: I'm running on Win7 64 bit. The extension wasn't installed on the first run. That's why I tried reinstallting webstorm, hoping it would retrigger the installation..

Comment: Chrome opens a tempfile and then just says "Waiting for connection from JetBrains WebStorm..."

Comment: Please make sure that the connection between WebStorm and the browsers isn't blocked by a firewall. Also the WebStorm log file may help to spot the problem. Could you please reproduce the problem, create an issue for it in [our tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and attach the log file to  the issue (use Help | 'Reveal Log' action to navigate to the log file)?

Comment: The best resource for configuring Javascript in WebStorm (PhpStorm too, and maybe any JetBrains IDE that can run Javascript) : http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/08/17/Debugging-with-JavaScript-with-WebStorm.aspx

Comment: I'm still having this problem, with chrome though. No URL is loaded..

Answer (score 2):

Although this post might be outdated:
You need to install the JetBrains IDE extension in the corresponding browser.
When this is done, check if the same host and port are specified for Webstorm as well as for the extension as well.